# Not able to access my internet

Tags: networking, internet

I am unable to access internet but wifi is showing connected and the icon of wifi is also visible on Ubuntu. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Check `ip route`.Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man ip ip-route  journalctl`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Can you please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using? Also, please provide a bit more history as to when you became unable to access the Internet. Did this happen after installation, after an upgrade, after installation an application? Finally, are you able to access any other part of your LAN through your WIFI connection, and are those other devices able to access the Internet? Thanks